# Erro ao tentar executar Eclipse: Java was started but return exit code =13

Tags: java, eclipse

Após ter o HD trocado, baixei e fui tentar executar o eclipse e ele retornou o erro:

`Java was started but return exit code =13`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- O que está causando esse erro?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Primeiro, verifique se o `JDK` está instalado.

Uma vez instalado, verifique se a variável `PATH` foi configurada.
Para isso,

1. Clique com o botão direito em Meu Computador e vá em propriedades;
2. Clique em Configurações Avançadas de sistema;
3. Clique em Variáveis de Ambiente;
4. Localize a variável `PATH` no quadro ‘Variáveis do sistema’. Clique sobre ela e depois sobre o botão ‘editar’;
5. Adicione o caminho onde o JDK foi instalado. Ex.: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin`
6. Dê `OK` em todas as telas abertas anteriores e tente abrir o Eclipse;

Comment: Eu tenho um problema parecido, mas no caso minha variavel de ambiente está certa, apontando p um java 1.6, deletei umas referencias de java 1.7 que tinham na máquina, mas nem usei, e agora o eclipse não abre mais

Answer (score 19):

Isso acontece por que você baixou uma versão do Eclipse de 32 bits e tentou executá-la com uma versão do Java de 64 bits, e vice-versa. Apenas baixe a versão correspondente ao seu JDK e isso estará resolvido.

Execute o comando `java -version` no *prompt* de comando.

Comment: não entendi o voto negativo, apesar de uma resposta breve, ela descreve uma possível situação que pode ocasionar o problema, apesar de não ser o problema do autor pode ser de outros. +1

Comment: Sim, eu tb não entendi, já tive este problema e resolvi acertando as versões Java vs Eclipse.