# Erro Encontrado no Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Instalei o Eclipse, o JDK e agora não consigo executar o programa pois surgiu este novo erro.

Comment: Instalou o eclipse correto com a arquitetura de seu `JDK` e `SO`?

Comment: Sim. x64bits de sistema

Comment: parece que seu eclipse é x86, leia o erro para notar.

Comment: O erro não seria pq ele pede o JDK 1.6?

Comment: baixe as ultimas versões do JDK e eclise ambos devem ser para a mesma arquitetura, a do seu sistema, logo se for 32 bits baixe o de x86 se for de 64 baixe o x64.

Comment: Parece ser o mesmo erro que esse: [Erro ao tentar executar Eclipse: Java was started but return exit code =13](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39207/3117)