# Erro ao abrir o eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Esse problema está ocorrendo depois que eu alterei o jdk estava com o 1.7 e passei a usar o 1.8. Alguém sabe a solução?
Segue mensagem ao tentar abrir o eclipse.

```
java was started but returned exit code=13 
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\lava\javapath\javaw.exe 
-DosgisequiredlavaVersion=1.8 -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -jar C:\ Eclipse-mais-atual
\ eclipse\\pluginstorg.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v201 50511-1540.jar
 -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -showsplash C:\ Eclipse-mais-atual \     eclipse\\plugins\ org.eclipse.platform_4.5.2.v20160212-1500 \ splash.bmp 
 -launcher C:\ Eclipse-mais-atual \ eclipse\ eclipse.exe -name Eclipse --launcher.library C:\ Eclipse-mais-atual \ eclipse\\pluginstorg.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32. x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417 \ eclipse_1611.d11 -startup C:\ Eclipse-mais-atual \ eclipse\\pluginstorg.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v201 50511-1540.jar --launcher.appendVmargs -exitdata 1730_60 -product org.eclipsesepp.package.jee.product -vm 
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe -vmargs -DosgisequiredlavaVersion=1.8 -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -jar C:\ Eclipse-mais-atual \ eclipse\\pluginstorg.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v201 50511-1540.jar OK •
```

Comment: É uma instalação nova? Qual a arquitetura do seu SO? 32 ou 64bits?

Comment: Veja se lhe ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39207/3117

Comment: 64 bits. Não é uma instalação nova,  isso começou a acontecer depois que alterei o path do jdk coloquei outra versão mas agora o path está na mesma versão que estava antes.

Comment: Sim, funcionou. Faltava dar uma editada no path...